# Iterate over Array and replacing at a certain value

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, splice

I have a question about feasibility of my code. I'm sure there is a better and more efficient way to write the function I wrote.

This is the **function**:

```
let i;
for (i = 0; i < ns.length; i++) {
  if (ns[i] > 1) {
    ns[i] = 3;
    const place = ns[i];
    ns.splice(place + 2, 1, 4);
    ns.splice(place, 1, 2);
    ns.splice(place - 1, 1, 1);
  }
}
```

**Initial Array** (this array have a length of upto 20 items):

```
ns = [1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 2 , 0]
```

**Result Array:**

```
ns = [1 , 1 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 4]
```

Believe it or not but this will suit my needs. But is there a better way than to just add up three times splice? It also extends my array if the number two of the initial array is at the end or beginning. I know I could just wrap it in another conditional but this seems so clumsy to me.

Thanks in Advance!
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So with help from Nina Scholz and a Friend i got to the right answer:

**Initial Array:**

```
["1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "0", "0"]
```

**Desired Array:**

```
["1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "3", "4", "0"]
```

**The Function:**

```
   isSibling() {
    const siblings = this.props.data.map(item => (
      item.progress
    ));
    let i;
    const place = '3';
    for (i = 0; i < siblings.length; i++) {
      if (siblings[i] === '2') {
        const num = i;
        siblings[i] = place;
        this.update(siblings, i - 1, '2');
        this.update(siblings, i + 1, '4');
        return siblings;
      }
    }
    return siblings;
   }
```

**Update Function:** 
to ensure the array is not enlongated or shortened:

```
  update(array, index, value) {
    if (index >= 0 && index < array.length) {
      array[index] = value;
    }
  }
```

Thank you for your help! :D

Answer (score 1):

You could replace splicing with deleting a single value and adding a single value with a simple assingment at the index.

For preventing updating values at not given indices, you could take a function which checks the wanted index and updates only given indices.

```js
function update(array, index, value) {
    if (index >= 0 && index < array.length) {
        array[index] = value;
    }
}
var ns = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0],
    length = ns.length,
    i,
    place = 3;
    
for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if (ns[i] > 1) {
        ns[i] = place;
        update(ns, place - 1, 1);
        update(ns, place, 2);
        update(ns, place + 2, 4);
    }
}

console.log(ns);
```

Comment: Thank you. Appears to be smother solution. If i add this line then the array still would expand `ns[place + 3] = 5;` .  Do you have an idea of how to avoid this withouth conditionals?

Comment: what should happen in that case? do you like to keep the length of the array?

Comment: does the *old* algo give the right result? maybe the problem is the fixed index of `3` for `place`, but you assign this value to the index with greater value of one and take this value fo later updating three values (or not if outer space).

Comment: somehow i still have an issue and i cant figure out whats going on. with this initial array: `["1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "0", "0"]`  i get this result: `["1", "1", 1, 2, "1", 4, "0", "0"]` i left numbers to show where it replaces but i dont get why it doesnt replace the 3 and why it does replace in the wrong places. i think it has something to do with the array/string/numerics... but if i have it all in a string format it still doesnt work

Comment: maybe it has to do with the replacements, as i wrote. the index for changing is a fixed value, mabe you want a dynamic value at the actual index ...? what result do you expect - and why?

Comment: yeah i definately want to get a dynamic  index for changing. since the array can get about a length of 20. so what i want to achieve is to search in the array for the number two and replace this one with 3 and the siblings with 2 and 4.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179037/discussion-between-nina-scholz-and-theweeezel).